# `Project Page Options` is missing from the IDE, what to do?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

While I was using D2007 I've really got used to [`Project > Project Page Options`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Project_Page_Options) feature to keep and view some free-form project notes, external references (these almost never being comfortably viewable in built-in HTML **designer**) etc. Now I have Delphi XE and `Project Page Options` is missing from Project menu, moreover, `projpageide150.bpl` mentioned in the documentation is not present in `bin` directory. How do i fix it? I'm really finding ability to **view** (not **edit**!) HTML documents in the IDE a very convenient feature.

Comment: I have seen several people mention the same problem since D2010, but no solution. Makes me wonder if the feature was removed, such as when support for Delphi.NET was dropped from the IDE.

Comment: IIUC I should have this menu item in my D2007 but I can't find it. There's no projpageide*.bpl to be found either. Is this a separate install or did I miss something else?

Comment: @Ulrich Gerhardt, good question. All I know - it is included and installed by default (might depend on RAD Studio edition, tho). Check if you have latest updates roll-up. Also, I think Welcome page package is required dependency for it.

Comment: I'm on "December 2007 Update" and have the Welcome Page activated. Do you have a `projpageide100.bpl` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeGear\RAD Studio\5.0\bin`? I don't.

Comment: @ulrich user is talking about XE

Comment: @David: I know. I just wanted to see (in my D2007 - we haven't upgraded yet) what this question is about and noticed I couldn't. :-(

Comment: @Ulrich Gerhardt, my exact version # is `11.0.2902.10471`, installed from DVD (as opposed to cumulatively updated from early release) onto clean system (might be related too, as I remember installer examines target system for licensing purposes)

Comment: @David Heffernan, Ulrich's phenomenon implies what there might be an installer bug which persists since migration to InstallAway - http://groups.google.com/group/borland.public.install.delphi/browse_thread/thread/006be2f4abc2ab89 - search this newsgroup for **sorry**, there are tons of such reports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it was dropped but has been re-instated. In my XE2 installation the projpageide160.bpl file is there, as is the `Project | Project Page options` menu. Neither are present in my D2010 installation.

Comment: Looks more like *broken but fixed* for me, as it still present in product documentation (not an on-line one). But what about XE version? I hadn't a chance to check 2010 for that.

Comment: You've got XE and say it's not there. I've got XE2 and it is there.

Comment: True. You'd need someone with XE to chip in. I skipped it.

Comment: A couple years late but it is not present in XE.